# Sequelize class model fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

For example I have such User model:

UserModel.ts:

```
import { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize'

export class User extends Model {
  declare id: number;
  declare name: string;
  declare surname: string;
  declare username: string;
  declare email: string;
  declare password: string;
  declare salt: string;
  declare uuid: string;

  declare public jwt_token: string | undefined;

  private static generateSalt(): string {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  }
  public hashPassword() {
    this.salt = User.generateSalt();
    this.password = this.password + this.salt;
  }

  public setJwtToken(jwt_token: string): void {
    this.jwt_token = jwt_token;
  }

  public getJwtToken(): string | undefined {
    return this.jwt_token;
  }

  public createJwtToken(): string {
    return "jwt_preview";
  }
}

module.exports = (sequelize: Sequelize) => {
  return User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(32),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    surname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(32),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(64),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(32),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: new DataTypes.STRING(257),
      allowNull: false
    },
    salt: {
      type: new DataTypes.STRING(12),
      allowNull: false
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user'
  });
}
```

And such DTO:

```
export interface LoggedUserDataDTO {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  password: string;
  mail: string;
  username: string;
  uuid: string;
  jwt_token: string;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is to convert founded user to DTO and send it as reply in my endpoint, but the problem is that when I'm converting model to dto like this

```
//Fastify
reply.code(200).send(loggedUser as any as LoggedUserDataDTO);
```

It works perfectly, but the fields which are not table rows (like jwt_token) aren't shown in my DTO or if I even send as reply my loggedUser without converting it to DTO.

So my question is how to show that field which is not a part of table columns.

Comment: Did you try `loggedUser.get({ plain: true })`?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt return jwt_token field

Comment: In this case you need to define a virtual field like `jwtToken` that will use `jwt_token` in getter and setter as a storage

Comment: Okay, thank u, that works fine